# Combining a static semi-circle with a sizeable rectangle with html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to combine a semi-circle that remains stationary and doesn't size with a full-width rectangle. These need to be together somehow so that I can put a textured background in that section. So far I've been able to do the above section of the space (in red) instead of where the textured space is. Eventually I want the red space to be transparent. See [Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7M2R.png)

```css
.u-bg-blue-over-chevrons {
  background: radial-gradient(circle 50px at bottom, #0000 97%, red), radial-gradient(rgba(86, 117, 143, 0.1), rgba(86, 117, 143, 0.1)), white url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='44' height='12' viewBox='0 0 44 12' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M20 12v-2L0 0v10l4 2h16zm18 0l4-2V0L22 10v2h16zM20 0v8L4 0h16zm18 0L22 8V0h16z' fill='%23d6d6d6' fill-opacity='0.4' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: center top, center, center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat, repeat;
  background-size: auto 50px, cover, auto auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-bg-blue-over-chevrons">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you already have what you want. You could make the red part the same color as the section above it to give an illusion of it being transparent. Unless the section above it is intended to have an image or another pattern.

Comment: Since this will be a footer, it'll be included on every page so if we do have an image/pattern for the row above it on certain pages, we don't want to create a one-off to update the footer specifically for that page. The 'red' section should be transparent.

Comment: You could do a static CTA section (usually a newsletter signup) that is always the section above the footer on every page to make life easier for you since you have a good solution already without the transparency. The other option would be crafting a `clip-path` that suits your needs but the code you have above would be useless in that event.